# Required value: must specify a volume type when statically provisioning PV

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to statically provision a PV with GCP SSD storage. Errors out with the following message:

```
The PersistentVolume "monitoring" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ cat storage.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
reclaimPolicy: Retain


$ kubectl apply -f storage.yaml
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/ssd created


$ cat pv.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: monitoring
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd
  capacity:
    storage: 50Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce


$ kubectl apply -f pv.yaml
The PersistentVolume "monitoring" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type
```

Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12+", GitVersion:"v1.12.6-gke.10", GitCommit:"aaf0906400b5fc1d858ce0566a571e4f3ed06b9f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-03-30T19:30:48Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Can you try `"ssd"` instead of `ssd`?

Comment: I think, when you use storageclass, you need to provide persistencevolumeclaim, then it will dynamically create a pv

Comment: @SureshVishnoi No. Commenting out storageClass doesn't help as well.

Comment: you need to create a PVC+storageClass==PV, when you are using stroageclass, you do not need to create a PV mannualy

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If using a provisioner, you usually don't create the PV on your own. Just create a PVC requiring that created storage class and GKE will provide the PV with the requested storage size and kind for you:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-retain-ssd-storage
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
  storageClassName: ssd
```

Comment: Can I specify `reclaimPolicy` through this PVC? I don't want to manually patch the pv and I want it to be automatically created by PVC.

Comment: As outlined in the original question: Add `reclaimPolicy` to the SC.

Comment: Also, run `kubectl get sc` to see available storage classes. GCE supports `standard` and `ssd`.

Answer (score 6):

No need to create *Storage Class*, just correct your requirements

see my file, Here HostPath is added.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: log-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/volume/nginx"
```

and PVC as

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: log-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
  storageClassName: manual
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `storageClass` provisioner is set to `kubernetes.io/no-provisioner`

```
~> kubectl describe storageclass harbor-registry-persistent-storage
Name:            harbor-registry-persistent-storage
...
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
```

you can create your `PV` as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  labels:
    component: harbor
  name: jobservice
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  local:                                             <------ mandatory field
    path: /mnt/kubernetes/persistent_volumes/harbor_registry_pv_0   <---- Note this path should exists in your kubernetes node 
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nodeAffinity:                                      <------ mandatory field
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: harbor-registry
          operator: In
          values:
          - harbor-registry-pv-0
  storageClassName: harbor-registry-persistent-storage
```

and your `PVC` should be able to attach with the above create PV:

```
k get pvc disable-pvc -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: disable-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: harbor-registry-persistent-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: jobservice
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi                  <------ The size should match with your PV storage
  phase: Bound
```

Answer (score 0):

References:

- [Kubernetes Error Codes: Must Specify a Volume Type](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-error-codes-must-specify-a-volume-type)
- [Required value: must specify a volume type when statically provisioning PV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955646/required-value-must-specify-a-volume-type-when-statically-provisioning-pv)
- [Optional: Bind a PVC to a specific PV](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/persistent_storage/selector_label_binding.html)

#### The issue:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: thin
```

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f pv.yaml
The PersistentVolume "minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type
```

#### One possible solution:

1. PV

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0
  labels:
      keylabel: valuelabel
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/volume/nginx"
```

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f pv.yaml
persistentvolume/minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0 created
```

2. PVC

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: thin
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: "minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0"
```

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/thin created
```

```sh
$ kubectl get pvc                                    
NAME   STATUS   VOLUME                                CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
thin   Bound    minio-tenant-log-minio-tenant-log-0   10Gi       RWO                           44s
```

#### Explanation:

Removed the `spec.storageClassName` from the `PersistentVolume` but added the `hostPath` to where we are going to locate the data; then created the `PersistentVolumeClaim` to include `spec.volumeName` so that `PVC` binds a specific `PV`. Problem solved!

Comment: Documented the same in my wiki, hope it helps people: https://github.com/cniackz/minio/wiki/Kubernetes-Error-Codes%3A-Must-Specify-a-Volume-Type/_edit